# Can't transform_caps in a custom gstreamer plugin

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm writing a gstreamer (1.x) plugin which applies an autogain to video frames. It will transform GRAY16_LE -> GRAY8.

I started by running the gst-element-maker tool in gst-plugins-bad-1.3.2/tools and using the *videofilter* template.

If I set my src and sink pad caps to "{GRAY8,GRAY16_LE}" I can get the following pipeline to run:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE ! videoautogain ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

However, it uses the same caps on the src and the sink (GRAY16_LE in this case). If change the sink caps to "{GRAY16_LE}" and the src caps to "{GRAY8}" I get errors connecting the pipeline. I think I might need to implement the GstBaseTransform->transform_caps function but I'm not sure and I don't know how I should implement it to force static but different caps on the two pads. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a simple example of what I needed to do (although in the GRAY8->GRAY16_LE direction instead of GRAY16_LE->GRAY8) in the gst-plugins-bad-1.3.2/ext/opencv/gstcvsobel.c plugin. Works great now!